# Trouble writing values from database to INI file

Tags: c#

I am trying to write values in an .ini file. I have made the connection to the database and can get the data but for the life of me I cannot get it to output correctly in the .ini file. I would like the output to be:

```
Row1 = column1 value - column2 value
Row2 = column1 value - column2 value
Row3 = column1 value - column2 value
```

.

```
//xcount is number of records in the data table
int xcount;
int primary;
primary = int.Parse(deviceNumTextBox.Text);
// get the data

if (primary == 99)
{
    xcount = int.Parse(countLabel1.Text);
    for (int t = 0; t < xcount; t++)
    {
        int j = 0;

        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        //foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string str;
            string nfloatAmt = (string)row[0];
            string ndeviceNum = (string)row["deviceNum"];
            //using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true))  // true is for append mode
            //{

            //}
            j++;
            str = "ROW " + j.ToString() +row["floatAmt"].ToString() + "^" + row["deviceNum"].ToString();
            source.Configs["STORE"].Set("FLOAT"+t, str );
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code is way too complex for a simple task.  Load the records from the database, loop through them, and append them to a StreamWriter that writes to a file.

Comment: Well, the first problem I see is that you want "=" and "-" in your output, but you don't have "=" or "-" in your code!  I think you haven't described the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to go through the code line by line with a breakpoint? This is what I'd do.